# Setting session variable in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

I'm following the excellent tutorial at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfq1xXzZeB4. Approx. halfway through the tutorial a form to add a new race should appear but does not when pressing the Add-button. I've changed the variable names slightly to accommodate the example to a pet-project I have.

In races.html (which equals to projects.html) I have:

```
<template name="races">
  {{#if showRaceDialog}}
    {{>raceForm}}
  {{/if}}
  ....
</template>
```

In krend.js I have

```
Races = new Meteor.Collection('races');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.setDefault('showRaceDialog', false);
  ...
}

Template.races.events({
  'click .addRace':function(evt, tmpl) {
     alert('showRaceDialog: ' + Session.get('showRaceDialog'));
     Session.set('showRaceDialog', true);
   }
})
```

The alert pops up with false in a new session and then true. But the session variable does not seem to propagate to the html-file. Probably due to me I guess but I can't see what is wrong.

When I remove the {{#if showRaceDialog}} and just render raceForm the Add form appears as it should. This is on Mavericks stock install, chrome, FF, safari.

regards
Claus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the helper that links it up:

```
Template.races.helpers({
    showRaceDialog: function() {
        return Session.get('showRaceDialog');
    }
});
```